# Is it possible to create a web3 daemon?

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I am using `nodejs` to call my smart contract's functions instead of calling within geth-client. Each time, when I run `node call.js`, it requires additional time `Web3` to connect into local ethereum network. When I make many calls, it consumes a lot of time. Also this daemon may help on during development and testing my contract's function calls.

Example code: `call.js` (using `Web3js`)

```
var mylib = require(contract.js);

Web3 = require("web3");
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

if(!web3.isConnected()){
    console.log("not connected");
    process.exit();
}
var myContractInstance  = web3.eth.contract(mylib.abi).at(mylib.address);
val="input";
myContractInstance.functionCall(val, {from: web3.eth.defaultAccount,gas: 300000 });
```

Alternative example code: `call.py` (using `Web3py`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
from web3 import Web3
import json
from web3.providers.rpc import HTTPProvider

web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

contractAddress='0x...';
with open('abi.json', 'r') as abi_definition:
    abi = json.load(abi_definition)
myContractInstance = web3.eth.contract(contractAddress, abi=abi);

eBlocBroker.transact().functionCall();
```

---

**[Q]** In order to gain some time (get rid of over and over `Web3` connection); it is possible to run a `Web3js daemon` or `Web3py daemon` on the background that connects into ethereum network **only one time** and later, I can use that daemon to make my smart-contract calls or talk with the ethereum network? 
If yes, how?

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but connecting web3 to a provider is very quick for me. How long would you say it's taking for you?

Comment: Its not that long but when I make hundreds of same call it cumulatively extends. Nearly around 5 seconds. That contract call takes 1ms in geth client. @Daniel Que

Comment: If you're calling `node call.js` hundreds of times, maybe you can refactor `call.js` to do something many times using the same web3 instance? Or you can write `call.js` as a function which takes a web3 instance as a parameter. I don't know the specifics of your situation, but you can probably work around faster than going through the trouble of implementing a daemon.

Comment: I call `node call.js`on different times, whenever a new request comes. So each time web3 got to connect to the ethereum network consuming 5 seconds at start-up. @Daniel Que

Comment: It's certainly possible.  The implementation of your daemon would be dependent upon the logic for triggering the calls to your contract.  Is it based on a timer?  Or would you need to have a mechanism to poke your daemon into making a call.

Comment: I need a mechanism to poke my daemon process into making a call. Or basically during development my contract, I can use it to test my contract calls. @Howard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be using **node-ipc** which should be much faster since it operate at a lower level.

Just separate your code into two file. One will keep the web3 connection alive and listen for new messages on the TCP channel to process it once the message will arrive from the other process (consumer).

**web3instance.js**

```
const ipc = require('node-ipc');

/**
* create your web3 instance here
**/
var mylib = require(contract.js);

Web3 = require("web3");
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

if(!web3.isConnected()){
    console.log("not connected");
    process.exit();
}
var myContractInstance  = web3.eth.contract(mylib.abi).at(mylib.address);

ipc.config.id = 'web3instance';
ipc.config.retry = 1500;
ipc.config.silent = true;

ipc.serve(() => ipc.server.on('functionCall', message => {
    myContractInstance.functionCall(message, {from: web3.eth.defaultAccount,gas: 300000 });
}));

ipc.server.start();
```

then the other one will send messages over the TCP channel that will be executed by the first process.

**web3consumer.js**

```
const ipc = require('node-ipc');

ipc.config.id = 'web3_instance_consumer';
ipc.config.retry = 1500;
ipc.config.silent = true;

ipc.connectTo('web3instance', () => {
  ipc.of['web3instance'].on('connect', () => {
    ipc.of['web3instance'].emit('functionCall', 'input');

    process.exit(1);
  });
});
```

You can create an emit for each method you want to test, or you can create a generic one and try to change the logic on the first file. Or, also, you might try to send the entire command in the *emit* and use the eval to process it in the first process (web3instance.js).

Hope it will help

Comment: I didn't understand how the communication is done in between `web3instance.js` and `web3consumer.js` @mirg

Comment: through the emit function. web3instance has the handler in case of events coming from the other app. Maybe I should've called consumer and producer to make it clear (and actually web3consumer is producing the events while web3instance is consuming it). The overall idea is that one process will keep the web3 connection open (instance) while the other processes the messages (web3consumer in the example) and the other process (who keeps the instance) will handle it through the event (web3instance in the example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use node and a library like [restify](http://restify.com/) to wrap your web3 code in a simple web service.  I haven't tested, but it should look something like the following (very simplified) example:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var mylib = require(contract.js);
var Web3 = require("web3");
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

if(!web3.isConnected()){
    console.log("not connected");
    process.exit();
}

var myContractInstance  = web3.eth.contract(mylib.abi).at(mylib.address);
var server = restify.createServer();

server.post('/method/:val', function(req, res, next){
    var val = req.params.val;
    myContractInstance.functionCall(val, {from: web3.eth.defaultAccount,gas: 300000 })
        .then(function(retval){
            res.send(200, { retval: retval });
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            res.send(err);
        });
     next();
});

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

You can then call your wrapper webservice methods using http..

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/method/123
```